# Is Symbol.for() a good replacement for String.getHashCode()?

Tags: javascript

To avoid using a very long string as a map key, is it a good idea to use a `Symbol`? Since Javascript does not have a default `hashCode` generation feature?

Comment: Could you please add your code, so we can understand the scale of your project.

Comment: hmm, not sure ... depends on what `String.getHashCode()` actually is

Comment: I haven't written a getHashCode() yet. But if i were to do something like the following:
https://gist.github.com/hyamamoto/fd435505d29ebfa3d9716fd2be8d42f0
would that be preferred over using Symbols?
I am planning on simplifying object lookup in either an object {} or a javascript Map. I haven't finalized which one I'm going to use.

Comment: Actually I'm thinking that I may need something a little more unique such as an MD5 hash instead of a number. So I may be doing something like the following to create a smaller key-like string for use in maps: https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-MD5